# rel=canonical on page but Google says not defined

Tags: html, canonical-link

I have a canonical tag in our head section but when I inspect the url in Google Search Console, Google says that the canonical tag is not defined.

```
<head>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head-meta" -->

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>2020 Women in HR Technology Summit</title>
<meta name="description" content="The Women in HR Technology summit, part of HR Tech, focuses on the training, technology & ethos needed to create a culture of inclusion in organizations. ">
<meta name="Keywords" content="Women in HR Technology, Women in HR Tech Summit, Gender Diversity">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.hrtechconference.com/images/og_session_image.jpg">
    <link rel=“canonical” href=“https://www.hrtechnologyconference.com/whrt” />
</head>
```

There is more code in the head but didn't want to clutter up post.  Things like tag manager and rounded corners etc.

Here is what is inside of Google's Inspection Tool

"
Crawl
Last crawl
Jun 6, 2020, 10:28:25 AM
Crawled as
Googlebot smartphone
Crawl allowed?
Yes
Page fetch
Successful
Indexing allowed?
Yes
Indexing
User-declared canonical
None
Google-selected canonical
Inspected URL
"
It says the user-declared canonical is "none". Just not sure if I put the canonical tag in the wrong place or not.  It works for our homepage but not any other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using curved quotes (`“`) instead of straight ones (`"`). This may have just happened in this question, but maybe check that the mistake didn't happen in your code as well, which would prevent the HTML attributes from being recognised.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  Didn't even think of that.  Thank you for the help.  I will fix it now.  Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Perhaps reading that section would help you as well John. "To put it another way, as long as your question is about programming, it's on-topic, even with the SEO tag. 
The catch, of course, is what comprises "about programming"? Let's contrast two questions to help clarify what we mean I have this code here. Google didn't handle it correctly, which hurt my SEO, but I started digging around and found this problem in my code. Some code here. How can I fix it? In this case, the question involves some code that has a direct problem. That SEO lead you to find the problem is irrelevant."